# Fit a SKlearn with arrays as a input

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to fit a `LogisticRegression`, the inputs are this:

[image]

`title`:
(example: df.title.iloc[0]) `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` has this form.

`caption`:
(example: df.caption.iloc[0]) `array([0, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0])`

Both variables have different length.

Then I tried to fit a `SKlearn-model` in this case a `LogisticRegression`. And this is the error I receive.

`LogisticRegression(random_state=0).fit(df, y_train_cat1)`

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: The arrays look very sparse.  Is there some meaning/significance to the position within each array?  Does each position in the arrays, in some row, have a non-zero entry?

Comment: @rickhg12hs The arrays come from encoding  text with one-hot-encoding, that is why are so many zeros...

Comment: If `title` and `caption` are derived from the same encompassing corpus, wouldn't all the arrays be the same length?